# Fetching Android ID with Kotlin for a webapp

Tags: android, kotlin

I can only find guides for javascript implementations of what I am trying to do. I need to pull some sort of unique ID and send it to my web app for Auth verification.

The error I am receiving is

```
in MainActivity.kt: (22, 29): Unresolved reference: Settings
```

This is my MainActivity.kt

```
import android.provider.Settings.Secure;

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private val androidId = Settings.Secure.getString(
    contentResolver,
    Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID
    )
}
```

For now I just want to be able to tack on the device_id as a php variable for my web app. Something like below:

```
private val url = "https://test.local?id=" + androidId
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've imported `android.provider.Settings.Secure`, not `android.provider.Settings`.

Either change your import to `android.provider.Settings` or use `Secure.ANDROID_ID` instead of `Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID`.